# How to determine type compatibility for a mixin template of a non-polymorphic type

Tags: c++, mixins, dynamic-cast

If I have a mix-in defined as...

```
template<class T> class Mixin : public T
{
    // mixin methods and members
};
```

...and declare it with T being a non-polymorphic class...

```
Mixin<NonPoly> mixin;
```

..and then have a base class pointer to it...

```
NonPoly* nonPolyPtr = &mixin;
```

...how can I later ensure nonPolyPtr is pointing to a Mixin type?

```
dynamic_cast<Mixin*>(nonPolyPtr)
```

The above does not compile because the base class is non-polymorphic.

I saw Boost has some trait classes that may help, but I'm hoping there's a simpler solution I'm overlooking.

Comment: Why does your mixin inherit from the main class? Shouldn't t be the other way round, `class T : public mixin<T>;`?

Comment: The base class is 3rd party and I can't touch it.  I want to add functionality to it with the mixin class.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking at the wrong requirements.  You don't need to do any casting here, but you may need to do some restructuring of your code.  If you have a relationship of classes A, which creates mixin and B which uses NonPoly, then just pass B the NonPoly pointer and use the mixin directly in A.  There should be no reason to give up the type information in A just to try to get it back again.  If there are more classes, separate them into those who know the mixin and those who know NonPoly, and it's the same relationship.

And it is very likely that if this is the case in the first place, a mixin design is not the proper approach.  Very often, mixins are used when simple containment is needed.  In my example with A and B above, you may have a Mixin class

```
template <typename T>
class Mixin
{
  T * GetObject()
  { return & t_; }

  // other methods that use t_
private:
  T t_;
};
```

and then just pass the object when it needs to be operated on.  Or even more common, if you are just passing T to some 3rd party library, you need no mixin at all.  Containment might not even be best.  The best way to maintain encapsulation is always to write file-scope algorithms when you can manipulate the type T through it's public interface and public 3rd party routines.

If you can explain why you think you need to lose the type information and then later recover, we might be able to show more clearly how you can restructure ownership so that doesn't need to happen, but since this type information never leaves the runtime (since you are looking to cast - your question implies it's not getting serialised or anything), I can assure you that there is some design where that type information is not lost in the first place.

Comment: With the sample code above, one cannot access T without a call to Mixin::GetObject().  I'd like direct access to T, while extending it with the Mixin, which is why Mixin derives from T.

Comment: You are confusing what you need to do with some assumption of how you want it to look.  The point of my post is that is the wrong way to go.  Choose the relationship that is required by the functional requirements, not how you feel.  You should always look to decrease coupling.  If code knows it's a mixin and wants to manipulate the T, it can access it by calling a method to get the T.  It is almost never the best design to inherit to extend a class.  The places where policy-based design works is in generic code that assumes the manager's workings - which is not what NonPoly is here.

Comment: I don't see how I'm confusing things.  I can't change T, but need to transparently extend its definition for one purpose (hence the Mixin), while all other usage still needs T only (and also can't be changed).  When T is passed for this one purpose, I want to verify it is a compatible Mixin type, but can't use dynamic_cast<> because T may be non-polymorphic.

Comment: As a contrived example, let's say I want to tag T with a timestamp of when it was allocated by a template<T> factory, where that timestamp is intended to be used in some template<T> function.  The template<T> factory allocates Mixin<T> and returns T*, while the template<T> function accepts T* and needs to check if it's a Mixin<T> before working with it.  If T is non-polymorphic, dynamnic_cast<T> can't be used.  Is there an alternative?

Comment: @bhassink: It's the "transparently extend it's definition for one purpose" that is making an assumption of how to implement.  This is propagating to assuming you need one function that does two things, one for T and one for Mixin<T>.  So now your design is getting worse, because now you have a function doing two things and "switching on types".  And if you ever need another set of functionality, are you going to derive from Mixin<T> to get NewMixin<T>?  And then, if you need the new functionality but not the old, now what?  As it grows, the stickier the design gets.

Comment: @bhassink: If you have to do two different things, pass the Ts to one function and the Mixin<T>s to another.  If you somehow need to store these things together, that is another requirement and has a simple solution.  The point is, there is no functional requirement that translates to: I need to derive my mixin from T and use a nonpolymorphic class polymorphically.  There is also no functional requirement that says: I need to lose the type information of whether my object is T or Mixin<T> except serialisation, which has well known solutions with object IDs and factories.

Comment: Let me state this slightly differently, as I've reviewed this conversation and found that I didn't stress something I normally would.  Why would you return a T* from the Factory and not a Mixin<T> *?  Why do you think you want to lose the type information?  There is no gain, since somewhere along the use chain, you know it is a Mixin<T> because you are static_casting.  There is nothing runtime about this - it's all static in-the-code-call-chain information.  When that's the case, losing type info is only "being clever" - but it's not clever because you are now not enforcing it in the compiler.

Answer (score -1):

If you are certain of its type just use `static_cast` to downcast. You also need to specify the template parameter in the cast `Mixin<NonPoly>*`.

```
template<class T>
class Mixin : public T
{
    // mixin methods and members
};

class NonPoly {
};

int main() {
  Mixin<NonPoly> mixin;
  NonPoly* nonPolyPtr = &mixin;

  Mixin<NonPoly>* mixinPtr = static_cast<Mixin<NonPoly>*>(nonPolyPtr);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing now, but had hoped for something a little more intelligent along the lines of dynamic_cast.

Comment: There is no need for `dynamic_cast` since `Mixin<NonPoly>` is not a runtime polymorphic class.